# Firebase: Email/Password auth works but other details of user doesnt get stored in users collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-thunk, react-redux-firebase

I'm using firebase to handle authentication using email&password auth but I also want to store additonal user details to a collection with uid that is generated from email/password auth.

The user gets registered but other details are not being stored to the `users` collection

Packages -

```
"@firebase/app": "0.4.10",
"@firebase/auth": "0.11.4",
"@firebase/database": "0.4.7",
"@firebase/firestore": "1.4.4",
"react-redux-firebase": "2.3.0",
"redux-firestore": "0.8.0",
"redux-thunk": "2.3.0"
```

I'm using redux-thunk to perform user registration asynchronously and then dispatching reducers.

In the below code, I've consoled `credentials`, `firestore`, they have the values and chained methods respectively, even the `res.user.uid` is there but for some reason user gets registered but user's details document doesnt get added to the `users` collection.

Async Action

```js
export const signup = credentials => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                credentials.email,
                credentials.password
            )
            .then(res =>
                firestore
                    .collection("users")
                    .doc(res.user.uid)
                    .set({
                        name: credentials.name,
                        username: credentials.username
                    })
            )
            .then(() => dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS }))
            .catch(err => dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_ERROR, err }));
    };
};
```

store.js

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";

import reducers from "./reducers/index";

import firebase from "../config/firebase";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reduxFirestore(firebase),
        reactReduxFirebase(firebase)
    )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Start by adding a `return` in front of firestore...set(...) so that it's part of your promise chain and so that you're waiting on the write before declaring it a success, and so that errors are captured.

Comment: @Kato Doesn't the whole `dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS })` take care of that? I'm not a redux expert btw, but that was my semi-educated guess.

Comment: @Kato That shouldn't be the problem since it's returning implicitly anyway.